# Checkbox's checkmark rendered weird in IE (6-Edge) and checkbox is misplaced

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In my IE checkbox's checkmark rendered weird in all web pages. Now I am facing with a misplaced checkbox issue too, I am not sure the two things has to do something with each other. See the same page (ASP MVC) in Chrome and IE below.

IE:

[image: IE]

Chrome:

[image]

*** Edit, added ***
The html code seems to be pretty correct, using bootstrap 3:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Keep me signed in field is required." id="KeepMeSignedIn" name="KeepMeSignedIn" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="KeepMeSignedIn" type="hidden" value="false">
        <label for="KeepMeSignedIn">Keep me signed in<span class="required" style="visibility:hidden;" aria-required="true">*</span> </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. My check box is rending the check mark, but it's placed it about 3 pixels higher in the check box in all IE emulations (verified by manipulating placement in Chrome and FireFox), but no matter how I update the placement, it stays in the same space. This is happening on a test server where it looks fine in my local environment. We are using a manipulation of awesome-bootstrap-checkbox that pretty much only changes the color of the check mark or the box to our company colors.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was getting similar placement issues when using the default MVC template for login (which seemed a little broken with bootstrap). I was getting weird margin/placement errors with the Remember Me checkbox.

In the end, I went for this:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
   </label>
</div>
```

Which ended up rendering nicely with bootstrap, as the label wraps the Checkbox. As this example shows:

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="RememberMe">
      Remember Me?
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: My sample is pure html, that part has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: @g.pickardou Yeah, sorry. Mentioning MVC might have confused the issue a little. Initially, my HTML was like yours, but have clarified the newly rendered HTML, which is slightly different to how yours is set up. It seemed a similar/related issue.